# All .exe extensions launch cmd.exe - how to undo this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry, desktop-icons

In troubleshooting a separate matter related to file icons and extensions, I right clicked a .exe icon on the desktop and set to open with cmd.exe. This was not what I wanted to do.

Then, all my .exe files were launching cmd.exe but from the file path in which the .exe icons were located.

Nonetheless, how do I undo this error? I right click a .exe icon on desktop and I don't see a open with menu item. I read that it involves a registry edit but and I came upon registry fixes but I want to know how this works conceptually and what keys should be altered to undo the error I made.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In Win7 I have "standard programs" in the start menu, which leads to "control panel - programs - standard programs". Is cmd.exe in this list?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/950505/when-you-run-an-.exe-file-on-a-windows-xp,-windows-vista-or-windows-7-based-computer,-the-file-may-start-a-different-program)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to registry at

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.exe]

And remove cmd.exe from there. The entries for .exe should be blank.